# ssh weak cipher removal... just benefits or drawbacks as well?

Tags: ssh, centos

Cent Os 6.5
Vulnerability scan suggests deleting the following weak cipher (Cent Os server 6.5):

```
3des-cbc

aes128-cbc

aes192-cbc

aes256-cbc

arcfour

arcfour128

arcfour256

blowfish-cbc

cast128-cbc

rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
```

My questions:

1. Am I right in saying that in order to delete those weak cipher I only need to add a line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` like the following:

*`Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr`*

2. Are there any drawbacks? I mean what about clients wanting to connect through ssh to my server?
   I'm referring to legacy clients

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Clients that only support weak ciphers would not be able to connect to your ssh service as you suggest.

I do not thing there are many clients that do not support the ciphers you'll keep tough.